# intellij idea community edition - code coverage?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

Looking at comparison matrix it looks like IDEA CE does not support code coverage at all. Bu there are lots of code coverage tools available, so perhaps it's possible to incorporate something into IDEA CE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, what doesn't work in CE is *integrated code coverage*. Any external tool would work. Emma for example integrates into maven and setting up maven goals inside IDEA is easy.

Just alter your pom.xml to include the emma maven plugin and it should work inside IDEA and on normal command line.

http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/

Comment: Hey Andreas, I did exactly the same and it generated a coverage.ec file, but how do I integrate it with my intellij IDE, so that I can view the code covered and the code not covered in different colors .

Comment: @sammyiitkgp, `Ctrl+Alt+F6`, click the `+` to add a file. You should be able to import `.ec` files there.

Answer (score 27):

Information for people visiting this question in 2014+.

Starting with Idea 14 (<s>currently available only in [Early Access Program](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP)</s> released in November 2014) that feature is also [available](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/06/intellij-idea-14-early-preview-is-available/) in a Community Edition.

> We think you’ll also appreciate the fact that Code Coverage tool,
>   Structural Search and Replace, and Type Migration refactoring have
>   become available in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Comment: @jevelop: You should reassign this answer as the correct one to prevent misleading information of the currently selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use sonar for the reports and add that to your maven pom.xml.

I find the reports way more convenient to read than the emma reports.

If you want to give it a try:

1) Download [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/)

2) add the sonar plugin to you pom.xml (maven 3 example)

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    <plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

3) start the sonar server

4) run mvn -DskipTests sonar:sonar

For more info, see the maven section of the [sonar docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven)

Comment: Since IntelliJ 14, code coverage is available in the community edition as well.